# Image is visible in Edit mode, but in Running mode Images are not visible

Tags: c#, image, uwp

Simple case. Need to add image to my button. While coding it is visible on the screen, but in Running on local machine mode it is invisible. I`ve tried png and jpg photos. Have this problem even in case of image outside the button.

```
     <RelativePanel Grid.Column="2">
                <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="vkIcon"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
                        Background="White"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="\Assets\Icons\ME.jpg" Height="48" 
                                      Width="48"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Image Source="\Assets\Icons\ME.jpg" Visibility="Visible"/>
            </RelativePanel>
```

Coding

[image]

RunningApp

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\Assets\Icons\ME.jpg` try `ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/ME.jpg`

Comment: @AVKNaidu thank you very much. it really helped!